# Is there any text that describes creation stories in chronological order?

Tags: creation

It creates lot of confusion when incarnation has the same name. For example, Laxmi was daugther of Khyati and also emerged from Samudra manthana; Daksha was son of Brahma and later became son of Prachetas too; Braham was born from golden egg but in one kalpa emerged from lotus of Vishnu's navel; Vishnu is from Trimurthi gods but his incarnation Vamana also shares the same name Vishnu (Krishna also shares few names of Vishnu such as Vasudeva, Madhava). Now many related stories differ a lot, for example, name and number of Daksha's daughters and their further progeny.

Is there any text that describes creation stories in chronological order? There is no beginning point as such because time is cyclic but is there any text that describes stories of current Kalpa or current manvantra at-least.

Comment: Brahmana Purana is a very good book at least for Vaivasvata Manvantara